# Distinct list of tags in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm rewriting my blog to use Jekyll. Jekyll uses the Liquid templating language so it makes it a little more difficult to learn how to customize.

I have a lot of `.md` files (markdown) one for each post. For every file I have in the following in the front matter:

```
---
layout: portfolio
title:  "Project Title"
date:   2015-12-12 17:53:00
categories: portfolio
tag: web
featured: true
---
```

In the tag section, I use one or more tags for each project. I know that with:

```
 {% for project in site.categories['project']%}
   do some stuff
 {% endfor %}
```

I iterate for every project. But I have the same tag for multiple files and I want to have a distinct list of tags. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Did you want to list projects by tag ? Not clear.

Comment: Exactly the above answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like [this](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/get-all-tags-uniques-in-multiple-collection-pages-without-a-plugin/1221/3):

---

```
<!-- Create empty arrays -->
{% assign tags = '' | split: ',' %}
{% assign unique_tags = '' | split: ',' %}

<!-- Map and flatten -->
{% assign article_tags =  site.articles | map: 'tags' | join: ',' | join: ',' | split: ',' %}
{% assign tutorial_tags =  site.tutorials | map: 'tags' | join: ',' | join: ',' | split: ',' %}

<!-- Push to tags -->
{% for tag in article_tags '%}
  {% assign tags = tags | push: tag %}
{% endfor %}
{% for tag in tutorial_tags '%}
  {% assign tags = tags | push: tag %}
{% endfor %}

<!-- Uniq -->
{% assign tags = tags | sort %}
{% for tag in tags %}

  <!-- If not equal to previous then it must be unique as sorted -->
  {% unless tag == previous %}

    <!-- Push to unique_tags -->
    {% assign unique_tags = unique_tags | push: tag %}
  {% endunless %}

  {% assign previous = tag %}
{% endfor %}
```

Then unique_tags should have the result you want, I think.

Comment: Fantastic is what I search for

Answer (score 4):

Updated solution from 2018:

```
<!-- Gather unique tags from articles -->
{% assign tags_articles =  site.articles | map: 'tags' | join: ',' | join: ',' | split: ',' | uniq | sort %}
<h2>Article tags: {{ tags_articles | join: "," | prepend: "[" | append: "]" }}</h2>

<!-- Gather unique tags from tutorials -->
{% assign tags_tutorials =  site.tutorials | map: 'tags' | join: ',' | join: ',' | split: ',' | uniq | sort %}
<h2>Tutorial tags: {{ tags_tutorials | join: "," | prepend: "[" | append: "]" }}</h2>

<!-- Combine and leave unique only -->
{% assign combo = tags_articles | concat: tags_tutorials | uniq | sort %}
<h2>Combo: {{ combo | join: "," | prepend: "[" | append: "]" }}</h2>
```

Comment: What it the meaning of `| join: ',' | join: ','`?

Comment: @DavideIcardi I don't remember jekyll template syntax at this point, but looking at it now I guess that it's the `| join: ',' | split: ','` sequence of operations that leads to having some nice side effect. White space trimmed? or maybe the type returned by split is accepted by uniq? Must be something along those lines.